# MAUI How to share Android app WITHOUT signing it or publishing it

Tags: android, maui, release

I need to send my app (which is just Android at the moment) to a non-tech-oriented co-worker (otherwise I'd upload the app to GitHub, but this person is just a salesperson, not a coder).

All the advice I see is how to publish an app (I'm not sure what to search for, so my Googling isn't that good here).  I don't want to do that.  Is there a bundled file that's created when I build in Release mode in Visual Studio that I could share with him?

I'm a total newbie with severe terminological deficiencies, so any explanation that a Golden Retriever would understand would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading

Comment: You need to generate a signed APK file. Signed APKs can be directly installed after download. Without signature Android will not allow the app to be installed.

Comment: You can generate a signing within minutes and do archive in VS to generate an APK to share

Comment: Thanks guys -- yeah, the APK file.  It sounds like it can be installed on the Android phone using ADB commands.  I thought it'd be more complicated than this.

Comment: All apk files are signed, the Android OS will not install an unsigned APK.  But signing just means generating a cert file-  there's no central authority for keys, so no registering your key and no cost.  Your IDE will generate one for you for debug builds